# How to install jQuery with Webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm very new to Webpack and I can't seem to get jQuery installed correctly. I've followed numerous instructions that I found online but whatever I try I still get a '$ is not defined' error whenever I try to include some jQuery in my page. My webpack config files are as follows (I have 3 config files: dev, prod and common).
I've removed all my previous, failed jQuery attempts from the config files.
To confirm, I have installed jQuery with npm and can see it listed as a dependency in my package.json file.

I'm also using bootstrap in the build which is working fine.

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it. I've been banging my head against a wall for so long now.

Thanks

Webpack config files...

dev:

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/template.html",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "header.html",
      template: "./src/header.html",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [require("autoprefixer")];
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

prod:

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contentHash].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/template.html",
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true,
        },
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "header.html",
        template: "./src/header.html",
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "[name].[contentHash].css" }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [require("autoprefixer")];
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

common:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js",
    vendor: "./src/vendor.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "imgs",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|ttf|svg|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[path][name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works for me. I append jQuery to the Plugins section in the Webpack config. So in your dev file:

```
// import webpack
const webpack = require('webpack');

... 

// add $ to plugins
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/template.html",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "header.html",
        template: "./src/header.html",
    }),
],

...
```

Import jQuery in your entry file (main: "./src/index.js")

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```